# regex.test() function not giving proper result

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I think I can explain my doubt by showing the code instead of exlpaining it::

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en-US'>
    <head>
        <title>Building Web Page for Client</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label for="message">Enter the banner Message: </label>
            <input type="text" name="userMessage" id="message" maxlength="32"><span></span><!--Form validation help text field--><br />
            <label for="zipcode">Enter the Zip Code: </label>
            <input type="text" name="userZip" id="zipcode" maxlength="5"><span></span><!--Form validation help text field--><br />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
        <div id="testElement"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript::

```
//Code block for element declarers for special function checkers
var inputList = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var zipField = document.getElementById('zipcode');
var regexForZip = /^\d{5}$/;
zipField.onblur = zipChecker;

function zipChecker(){
    if(checker1 && checker2){
        if(!(regexForZip.test(zipField)))
            inputList[1].nextElementSibling.textContent = 'You can only enter numbers';
        else
            inputList[1].nextElementSibling.textContent = '';
    }   
}
```

Now, the HTML is pretty simple , and the javascript even simpler. Now, can you look at the `checker1` and `checker2` booleans? Both of those are true(Sorry about not including them in this code, the code is a bit large).

I defined a regular expression which will ONLY contain 5 digits, nothing else. Now what I do is I try to take the second input element, and whatever the user enters, I check that for only 5 digits. By the code, if the input doesn't match the regular expression, the next `<span>` tag will have a text prompting the user, otherwise, it will be empty.

NOTE: For this case, the input will be 5 characters long.

Now here is the problem: No matter what I give as the input, the page prompts me to only enter numbers, which doesn't makes sense. Suppose, I enter 11111. It tells me what it should have told me if I entered any other character than a number.

What's the problem in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running your `RegExp` against a DOM `Element`

```
if (!regexForZip.test(zipField))
```

What you might want to test for is the *value* of the element, which is a `string`:

```
if (!regexForZip.test(zipField.value))
```